# Is this wrong and why it's not ? ASP.NET MVC ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

Here is an example of my code where I'm displaying information about my customers:

```
<table class="table table-striped  jambo_table bulk_action">
   <thead>
      <tr class="headings">
         <th class="column-title">Address </th>
         <th class="column-title">Title</th>                                            
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    @foreach (var customer in ViewBag.Customers)
    {
     <tr>
      <td>@customer.Code</td>
      <td>@customer.DefaultName.Name</td>
     </tr>
    }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see guys I'm looping through `ViewBag` to display some data in my table, 
and I tested it when there is no data in `ViewBag.Customer`, and It didn't throw any exception, 
how come `foreach` is not throwing exception on empty list?

I thought I will get something like :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

if I try to loop through `ViewBag.Customer` when there is no data in..

How come ?

Comment: Show us your controller class. The whole class.

Comment: If it is an empty list it will not throw an error. If it is null there should be an error (I think).

Comment: Why don't you use a ViewModel passing all properties to your view strongly typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foreach` loop calls the `GetEnumerator` method. It would not throw an error if it is empty enumerator (ie: it just exit the loop).

If the collection is null, this method call results in a `NullReferenceException` as it is unable to get the enumerator. In this case, your controller must have returned an empty list for it to not throwing an error.

Comment: I just realized that my Controller which is returning list of Customers from database, is acctually returing empty list in a case there is not items in.. so yes your answer is true,ž
list is not null it's empty..

Answer (score 0):

As @hsoesanto said an IEnumerable calls the GetEnumerator which returns an instance of an IEnumerator but it doesn't throw any exception if the collection is empty.

This is the original code of ICollection

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
  return this.items.GetEnumerator();
}
```

but if you go deep lets say to the implementation of a List that implementes ICollection when it returns the Enumerator for the List, you see the check against the size of the list

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
[Serializable]
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
   ....

  [__DynamicallyInvokable]
  public bool MoveNext()
  {
    List<T> list = this.list;
    if (this.version != list._version || (uint) this.index >= (uint) list._size)
      return this.MoveNextRare();
    this.current = list._items[this.index];
    this.index = this.index + 1;
    return true;
  }
```

As you can see on this line

**if (this.version != list._version || (uint) this.index >= (uint) list._size)**

This means that when you are trying to iterate over a collection of elements that is empty, the MoveNext returns false and after that the foreach ends.

So going back to your ViewBag, you should not receive any error or exception if the Customers is not null, first the compiler detects on run-time that you are using a Collection of element on your ViewBag, and if it is not null, then it iterates over it calling the GetEnumerator over that collection that returns the IEnumerator and call the MoveNext and the Current to get each element of the List.